# Power Automate - Duration (Approvals)

Tags: power-automate

Are there any expiration period for this Power Automate - Approvals when the user taking more time to submit the decision?

[image]

[image]

I tried with some trial data but, need to get an idea from an experienced person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flows have a timeout period of **30** days.

You can refer to this documentation for more information.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/limits-and-config#duration-limits

If your approval is likely to run for more than 30 days, read this article.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/modern-approvals#create-long-running-approvals